# Annotation of State and country name in React-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I've started working on a map related project using React-Leaflet. The basemap provided by OpenStreetMap is politically incorrect wrt India, so i decided to find right geojson data and display its layer through GeoJson from 'React-Leaflet'. 
Right now its only showing the borders/polygons, but i want to display the name of country and state as annotation similar to OpenStreetMap's basemap. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Country and state are the same aren't they? So you want to display only India on top of geojson or you want to display the district names?

Comment: both India and district names